# How can I improve the resolution of png files used by doxygen in html output?

Tags: html, latex, png, doxygen

doxygen can create mathematical formulae using LaTeX. From the LaTeX output, it generates (I don't know how) .png files and includes them into the html documentation. Unfortunately, the resolution of those .png files is rather poor. I'd like to improve that but couldn't find any entry in the .dox file related to that. Help appreciated.

Comment: Did you resolve it? Or did you maybe file a feature request?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look at the MathJax possibilities in doxygen (set USE_MATHJAX to YES).

Comment: okay. perhaps you can tell me more about this. mathjax seems for servers. How do I go about it for doxygon on my laptop? (this answer is too thin to deserve an accept)

Comment: When you are online the default settings are OK to use it. When being offline you have to download MathJax beforehand and install it and adjust the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile) accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no direct way to do this. I tried resolving this by increasing the font size in the formulas to 20 (from the default 10). And then forcing the formulas to 50% of the source image size, using CSS. You can set `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` to e.g. `doxygen_modify.css` (do not use `doxygen.css` as that would overwrite the main CSS file).

Inside, you can put:

```
.formulaInl {
    -ms-transform: scale(.5, .5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5, .5); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: scale(.5, .5);
}
```

and this reduces the images to the original size, hence increasing the DPI. **It is imperfect** as there is now empty space around the image but it might not be an obstacle, depending on how you use the formulas in the documentation (wouldn't matter if you use centered formulas).

Alternatively you can crawl the generated HTML files, look for `img` tags with class `formulaInl` and manually specify the modified width and height in pixels based on the size of the file. In Linux, this is a matter of a few minutes of bash scripting. It has the obvious downside that anyone using your Doxygen file to generate the documentation herself will end up with huge formulas.